# Is there a way to send Authorization in Header from Zuul apigateway to auth-microservice

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, authorization, microservices, netflix-zuul

I work in project that uses microservice architecture with JWT, every thing is good but when I send the Authorization in the request from client (Angular app) it is checked by the api-gateway (ZuulFilter) and after that the request is sent to auth-server, the problem is that  I don't find the Authorization in the header and every data is lost. Any one has an idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add he property **sensitive-headers** in zuul properties and remove "Authorization" from default value as explained [here](http://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/pass-authorization-header-to-downstream-microservice/) and [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_cookies_and_sensitive_headers)